# How do I get the current url in web2py?

Tags: url, web2py

In web2py how do I get the complete url of the current page?  I want the (possibly rewritten) url that appears in the browser address bar.

e.g.
http://www.example.com/products/televisions?sort=price&page=2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest method to generate this is probably:

```
URL(args=request.args, vars=request.get_vars, host=True)
```

You could also assemble the URL this way:

```
'%s://%s%s' % (request.env.wsgi_url_scheme, request.env.http_host,
               request.env.web2py_original_uri)
```

Comment: The first method answers my follow on question of how to get full url without query parameters.  Seems `URL(args=request.args, host=True)` does the trick.  The 2nd method is giving `http://www.example.com/None`

Comment: Sorry, it's `request.env.web2py_original_uri` (corrected above). Note, if you include `{{=response.toolbar()}}` on a page, you can see all the elements of the `request` and `response` objects (as well as the `session` and database stats).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread - this is what it took for me in 2017 to get the original url:

```
url = '%s://%s%s' % (request.env.wsgi_url_scheme, request.env.http_host,
           request.env.request_uri)
```

Close to the previous answer but the uri was elsewhere.