# Simplest way to indicate current response.menu item to web2py's MENU helper?

Tags: web2py

It is understood that there are two ways the `MENU` helper can use to indicate the current menu item and append a `web2py-menu-active` class to the `<li>` for that item. Using expressions for the 2nd item of each menu item is a very manual cookie-cutter approach involving a lot of cut and paste.

Therefore, supplying the `active_url` argument is more code-efficient.

Apparently [the way to get the current URL in web2py has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827793/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-web2py) but I would like to confirm that the below would be the ideal code for the purpose of informing `MENU` of which menu item to append a `web2py-menu-active` to:

```
MENU(    ...., active_url=URL(args=request.args, vars=request.get_vars, host=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
{{=MENU(response.menu, 
    _class='nav navbar-nav', li_class='dropdown', 
    ul_class='dropdown-menu', active_url=request.url)}}
```